# Use resources.pipeline.xxxx.runName in the name of triggered pipeline... with stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yaml build pipeline in azure devops having the name created like this :
`name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)_$(Date:yyyy-MM-dd)$(Rev:.r)$(branchName)`

I have a release pipeline triggered by that one like this :

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyBuild  # identifier for the resource used in pipeline resource variables
    source: MyBuild   # name of the pipeline that produces an artifact
    trigger:
      branches:
        include: 
        - main

name: $(resources.pipeline.MyBuild.runName).$(Rev:r)
```

But unfortunaly the name is not properly generated.

I found a workaround here: [Manually triggering Devops pipeline with pipeline resource should use latest resource pipeline run for that branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396882/manually-triggering-devops-pipeline-with-pipeline-resource-should-use-latest-res)

That one works fine if my pipeline has only one stage, like this :

```
name: Release-$(Rev:r) for Build # actual build number will be appended at runtime by logging command

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Build.BuildNumber) $(resources.pipeline.MyBuild.runName)"
```

However, it does not work in a multistage pipeline, like this:

```
name: Release-$(Rev:r) for Build # actual build number will be appended at runtime by logging command

stages:
- stage: BuildNumber
  jobs:
    - job: BuildNumber
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Build.BuildNumber) $(resources.pipeline.MyBuild.runName)"
```

Any idea about how I can rename my Release pipeline ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Comment: same, need a solution for this.

Comment: Would it be possible to use Build.TriggeredBy.BuildNumber instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml